# Adding and manipulating multiple Set-Cookie headers in IIS

Tags: iis, cookies, iis-10

I have a use-case where I need to add multiple Set-Cookie headers to all responses from IIS.

For one cookie I can simply add a custom response header "Set-Cookie" to a custom value, use an outbound rewrite rule that finds this header and then a custom rewrite provider to rewrite the value of this cookie to desired value. This works fine.

```
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="My cookie rule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern=".*\{my_custom_value_pattern\}.*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="{MyCustomProvider}" />
  </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

The problem for the second Set-Cookie is that IIS does not allow me to add another "Set-Cookie" header as it complains about a header with that name already exists.

If [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) were still valid I could just use concatenated values in one header but since [RFC6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt) deprecates this I need to use multiple Set-Cookie headers.

How can I get IIS to return two or more custom Set-Cookie headers where the values are provided by custom rewrite providers?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was very simple, I do not have to add custom header that I later manipulate, I can set new headers directly in the rewrite rule by setting the property `replace` in the action to false;

```
<rule name="Cookie 1">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^.*$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" value="mycookie1={MyCustomProvider:inputvalue}; Path=/" replace="false"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Cookie 2">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^.*$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" value="mycookie2={MyCustomProvider:inputvalue}; Path=/" replace="false"/>
</rule>
```